# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'buildTransaction' - Python Web3 Solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, python, pancakeswap

I'm using this code to swap token USDT to token A but it has been stuck by this error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'buildTransaction'

Here is my code:

```
path = [tokenA,tokenB]    
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    buyamount,
    int(minimum),
    path,sender_address,
    (int(time.time()) + 10000).buildTransaction({
        'from': sender_address,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei(float(gas), 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address),

    }))
```

Please give me an advice. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced an parenthesis

```
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    buyamount,
    int(minimum),
    path,sender_address,
    (int(time.time()) + 10000) /// <--- 1 parenthesis was missing here
).buildTransaction({
    'from': sender_address,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei(float(gas), 'gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address),
}) /// <--- there was 1 extra parenthesis here
```